# Rails: Accessing one model from another model when using Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, cron

Currently I have this in my schedule.rb:

```
every 1.minutes do
    runner "Cronjob.cronjob"
end
set :output, File.join(path, 'log', 'cron.log')
```

and in my Cronjob model:

```
class Cronjob
  def self.cronjob
    events=Event.find :all
  end
end
```

I don't want a table to accompany this model so hence the lack of `< ActiveRecord::Base`

However I'm being told that:

```
Could not find table 'events' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Is this as a result of the missing < ActiveRecord::Base or is it because this is a cron job or is it something else,like something to do with class and instance methods?

Comment: Do you have an *events* table?

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness yes I do thats the thing. could it be that cron jobs are external as such. Note this is run on localhost

Comment: Are you running that code in another environment, where the table doesn't exists (fe. development instead of production or viceversa)?

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness that could be it indeed give me a minute to check

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness it isn't that